# Контекст внутри $().click(function(){})?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  console.log( $('form[data-ajax]') ); //Возвращает domHtmlElement

  $('form[data-ajax]').click( function( event ){
    console.log(this);// возвращает чистый html, как будто я вызвал .html()
  } )

})
```

Что я делаю не так? Всё же работало всегда, this внутри .on(function(){}) всегда возвращал domHtmlElement? Нет?

Всё ещё не понятно, чем объясняется такое поведение?

```
element = $('form.form-ajax');

$( element ).submit(function(event){
    console.log(typeof element); //object
    console.log(typeof this); //object
    console.log(this); //html
    console.log(element); //jquery object
    console.log(element === this)//false
}
```

Получается, element и this - объекты разных типов? Если да, то почему так получается? Я же .on вешаю на jquery object, значит и контекст должен быть в коллбэке jquery object, нет? А если нет (я вижу, что нет), то почему так происходит и где подробнее почитать про это?

Comment: [mcve] в сниппете?

Comment: В фф во втором случае отображается дом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `$(...)` всегда возвращает *объект jQuery*.

Таким образом следующее утверждение **неверно**

```
console.log( $('form[data-ajax]') ); //Возвращает domHtmlElement
```

---

функция `console.log` сама решает как именно отобразить переданный аргумент и так как ее поведение зависит от реализации в браузере, следующее утверждение также **неверно**

```
console.log(this);// возвращает чистый html, как будто я вызвал .html()
```

---

Значение `this` внутри обработчика события устанавливается в Html элемент, на котором это событие подписано.

Таким образом сравнение html элемента с объектом jquery

```
element === this
```

Ожидаемо вернет *false*.

Answer (score 0):

Вам возвращается элемент. Вы этот элемент пытаетесь вывести в лог, для этого он преобразовывается в строку. Алгоритмов преобразований может быть куча. В данном случае берется свойство `outerHTML`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log(typeof $('#test'));
  $('#test').click(function(event) {
    console.log(typeof this);
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.id);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">Test</div>
```

Comment: Почему он тогда в первом случае этого не делает?

Comment: В первом случае вы выводите не дом, а объект.

Comment: @DanilaAlpatov Кто не делает? Запустите мой пример и все увидите

Comment: Я изменил вопрос слегка. Всё ещё плохо понимаю происходящее.

Comment: @DanilaAlpatov Вашим изменением вопроса Вы полностью его переформулировали

Comment: Нет, вопрос остаётся тот же:
Контекст внутри $().click(function(){})?

на что ссылается this внутри этой функции и почему он не равен объекту, на который я вешал обработку события.

Comment: @DanilaAlpatov он ссылается на DOM объект. Именно на них Вы и вешаете события. Но перечисляете Вы эти элементы при помощи **обернутого** набора jQuery